# Finding the direction of several radio beacons using a faraday cage and a radio receiver

Tags: electromagnetism, radio

I'm trying to build a system that can detect the direction of a set of radio beacons operating on the same frequency.

In order to do this I have planned to use a normal radio antenna placed inside a faraday's cage that has an open side. Could this work?

I have tried to search for directional radio receivers but they tend to also receive some signal from the sides, which will interfere when multiple beacons operate on the same frequency, or they use multiple antenna’s/the Doppler effect. Both will also interfere with the  frequency of the antenna.

So, can we make an effective directional radio detector using a radio receiver inside a faraday's cage with one side open mounted on top of a Stepper motor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideal receiver would be a [parabolic reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_reflector) with your detector at the focus. In other words a small version of the detectors used in [radio astronomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_astronomy). Your idea of an open cube with the detector at the centre would be an approximation to this, though I suspect rather a poor one with a rather limited angular resolution.